# Hanukkah candles should start from the right, but which right?

Tags: chanuka

It is known that the first Hanukkah candle should be on the right, and every day another candle is added to its left.

My question is, which right? If I am lighting the candles in a window or suchlike facing outside, my right will be left from the perspective of outside observers.

So where should it be - to the right of the person lighting, or to the right as seen from outside?

Comment: Is that known? I think it's actually a big Machloket. Any opinion you can imagine probably exists.